# Storyboard file will not open after interfaceBuilder throws error -1

Tags: ios, xcode, git, swift, interface-builder

I work with GIT, and after pull/pushing the project repository, I went to run the application to test I pushed a working version. However, after running the app, I am struck with this error immediately upon compile:

"The document "Setstory.storyboard" could not be opened. The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.InterfaceBuilder error -1.)"

I am running the latest version of XCode(7.0.0) and OSX 10.10.5.

I have tried googling this for an entire day, and still have not been able to figure it out. Has anybody else seen this?

Comment: did someone else edit the storyboard at the same time as you? git is very bad at merging storyboard changes because the file can change very drastically even from small changes, so in general 2 people shouldnt edit a storyboard at the same time otherwise it can put unwanted xml in the storyboard which will make it invalid

Comment: Yes, but usually git flags the merge issues so I can manually fix them through the terminal window running VIM

Comment: it sometimes auto-merges if there is no conflict, which doesnt mean that it did the right thing

Answer (score 0):

Your storyboard contain merge conflicts. Resolve them, and then try opening it then.